# How to write adb shell commend in java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()?

Tags: java, android, adb

I need to use adb connect pc to device and do some checking.
So I try to use 
`java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` to get `adb` shell result into my program.
But I don't know how to write the adb shell commend in the `exec` call,
something like:

```
String cmd =adkHome + "adb.exe -s " + device + " shell ls";
```

then `cd data/app`

How do I do this?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen after cd ? Do you mean 'shell ls /data/app'?

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for?

```
    
    String cmd = "adb shell ls";
    String cmdreturn = "";
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
    pr.waitFor();
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
         System.out.println(cmdreturn);
    }
```

As far as preforming actions in a shell, I would recommend writing a shell script that you execute. In this case instead of

```
    
    String cmd = "adb shell ls";
```

Replace it with

```
    
    String cmd = "shellscript.sh";
```

Cheers!

Comment: adb is a client and it runs in a host . if you try to execute  adb in a android shell it will produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to run this on the phone from your java app, you just need:

```
String cmd = "ls";
```

Comment: I means I have a java program run in pc which will triger the adb commend. like the cmd =adkHome + "adb.exe -s " + device + " shell". Then I need to follow up by another commends which try to run in the shell adb opened. like "ls" and "cd "...

Comment: Ok - I don't think you can do what you want then.  As far as I understand it, each adb.exe command starts a new shell so even if you 'cd data/app' in one shell, it won't preserve that for the next.  If you are just trying to ls a specific directory, you could do as @dtmilano suggested and issue a fuller command 'ls /data/app'.